# File input empty but an empty "file" shows up in Request.Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has the following file input:

```
<input type="file" name="SchemaFiles" id="SchemaFiles" class="form-control" multiple/>
```

My model has this attribute:

```
  public List<HttpPostedFileBase> SchemaFiles { get; set; }
```

When I select one or two files for this input, everything works fine. However, if I don't select any files and submit the form, then `SchemaFiles.Count` is `1`, and `SchemaFiles[0]` is `null` (but does exist). `ModelState.IsValid` is `true`.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do not add tags of unrelated languages!

Comment: That code in the model is c#. I guess it's more of an asp.net-mvc question (tagged) though. Does that really warrant a downvote?

Comment: And you added the C tag - why?

Comment: I must  have typo'd the c# tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by-design and looks like the root cause is the browser.
See these links for reference:

- ASP.NET work item: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/188
- Stackoverflow article: [Why IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> count is 1 when I upload 0 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614892/why-ienumerablehttppostedfilebase-count-is-1-when-i-upload-0-files) and
- Blog article: http://michaelsync.net/2014/04/29/asp-net-mvc-multiple-files-upload-bug-or-by-design-issue

Comment: I'll see if the browsers have a bug report or explanation.

Comment: I think most browsers will do it this way, probably legacy reasons that will just stick. My point is that the data coming in over HTTP has an empty filename when no files are selected (at least according to these posts) and the correct way to solve this is to filter it out in your server code. In general you should always distrust data coming from the browser, always check and filter out invalid data.