# Uploading multiple files using ICollection of HttpPostedFileBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying make multiple file upload and to do this I am using `ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase>`. I choosed to use `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` because using `ICollection` I can use the function `Count` to check size of `ICollection`. It works very well, the problem is when I try check the size it always has one value even it is empty, even I don't select any file it has one value, and I don't know why it's happens.

Why ICollection always has one value even I don't choose a file ? How could I fix this ?

**Model**

```
public ICollection<HttpPostedFileBase> imagens  { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.imagens)" class="col-md-12 control-label">Imagens (Max.10) </label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imagens, new{
                                                                Class = "form-control",
                                                                placeholder = "Escolha as imagens",
                                                                multiple = "multiple",
                                                                type = "file"
                                                                })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imagens)
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
//check if ICollection is empty. It still doesn't works. 
if (model.imagens.Count == 0){
                jsonResposta.Add("status", "0");
                jsonResposta.Add("msg", "Add at least one picture");
                return Json(jsonResposta);
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File input empty but an empty "file" shows up in Request.Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520301/file-input-empty-but-an-empty-file-shows-up-in-request-files)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your collection type (`ICollection`). The browser (chrome is what i checked) is always sending  form data item of  `application/octet-stream` type even though you do not select any file. This happens for single file selector and multiple file selector. I believe it is the Model binder which is handling it properly for the single file, but not handling it properly when your property type is HttpPostedFileBase collection.

Your best solution now is to filter it out your self.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
{
    var validFiles = model.imagens.Where(g=>g!=null).ToList();
    //use validFiles  from now onwards
   // to do : Return something
}
```